# New to java can't figure out how to use paint method

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint

I am trying to learn the paint method and get a ball to move across the frame. here is my code so far. w=.

I currently have two classes One is the main and one for the ball.

this is the main class
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

```
public class PaintTest extends JPanel {
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

public void moveBall(){
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 1;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Ball ball = new Ball(x,y);

    while(true){
        ball.moveBall();
        repaint();
    }
    }
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.setColor(Color.magenta);
    g.drawLine(0,100,500,100);
    g.drawLine(0,101,500,101);
    g.drawLine(0,102,500,102);
    g.drawLine(0,103,500,103);

    g2.fillOval(x,y,35,35);
}
}
```

and here is the ball class

```
 public class Ball {

   int x,y;

   public Ball(int x, int y){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}
}
```

now when i compile I get an error saying cannot find symbol ball in class PaintTest even though I am calling it from the class Ball. I am aware of the repaint error as i do not know what to put in front of it.

Comment: Where did you get this code? From a tutorial? If so, don't follow it since you should never paint directly in a JFrame. Instead draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel as any decent Swing tutorial will show you. Don't guess at this stuff. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)

Comment: I wrote the code myself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: You've created Ball in your static main method, and it is only visible within that method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels where else would I create it

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt, but on seeing this and other errors and questions, I have to wonder if you're putting the cart before the horse here. You're trying to learn a complex corner of Java -- Swing animation -- **before** you even know basic Java. Isn't this backward? Wouldn't you be much better served to learn the basic rudiments of the language first? I strongly advise you to do so. Get some books, go through the tutorial, learn your for loops, your ArrayLists, your static vs instance, protected vs private vs public first. You will save yourself (and us) much frustration by doing this.

Comment: I have books I know what these things mean I simply get them confused. This is the first taste of coding ive had in my life so im sorry if I seem "dumb" compared to your knowledge on the subject. now if you could simply tell me where to create this ball and what to put in front of the repaint I would greatly appreciate it. I can figure the rest out on my own

Comment: I told you already where to place it. In the PaintTest class. It must be a field of the class. Look up **scope** since variable scope is your problem here.

Comment: there isnt a constructor to place it in

Comment: It needs to be in PaintTest since it must be declared in a place that allows it to be visible where it is needed. And your questions aren't "dumb" so much as ignorant. That's OK, we're all born ignorant, but I am criticizing your order of learning. The best order of things is to first learn basic Java before tackling advanced topics. This is common sense.

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw in a JPanel
2. In its `paintComponent` method **not** in its paint method -- this gives you double buffering.
3. Call the super's paintComponent method in your override. This allows the JPanel to do housekeeping drawing including erasing the oval image at its old position.
4. Don't use a `while (true)` loop as this can cause serious Swing threading issues. Use a Swing Timer instead.
5. In the Swing Timer, increment your animation variables and then call `repaint()`. This will tell Swing to repaint the component which will re-draw the oval in the new location.
6. Don't guess at this stuff as that leads to frustration since Swing graphics coding is a different beast. Instead check the tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). Also check out [Performing Custom Painting with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).
7. Graphics2D goodies: RenderingHints can be used to smooth out your image jaggies.
8. More Graphics2D goodies: Stroke can be used to draw thicker lines when needed.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PaintTest extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(5f);
   private int x;
   private int y;

   public PaintTest() {
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // to smooth graphics
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      g2.setColor(Color.magenta);
      Stroke initialStroke = g2.getStroke();
      g2.setStroke(STROKE);
      g.drawLine(0, 100, 500, 100);
      g2.setStroke(initialStroke);

      g2.fillOval(x, y, 35, 35);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         x++;
         y++;
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      PaintTest mainPanel = new PaintTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("PaintTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: could you possibly show me an example of how to do what you suggested?

Comment: @Cookie: yep, check my code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+swing+animation).

Comment: @Cookie: You're getting many answers with bad code. Please see posted code here in the question for better code. Please ask if anything confuses you.

Comment: This does not change the multi-jframe issue

Comment: why does the paintCompenent have a protected modifier

Comment: @Cookie: because that is how it is declared in its super class. You never want to make it more visible than it has to be.

Comment: oh ok. im new to java so I dont really understand what all of these different modifiers mean

Comment: @Cookie: [Access Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Nevermind about that, I was looking at your earlier submission and noting the problem of the user having 2 jframes because Ball was an instance of the same class who's constructor created the frame. In your current version of the code this is fixed. Just trying to help... (PS) Wouldn't it be preferable to repaint the panel in another thread?

Comment: @ManOfPanda: OK, thanks for the correction. Edit: no. It doesn't matter which thread calls `repaint()` the painting will be done on the EDT regardless. The advantage of using a Swing Timer is that all code in its ActionListener is called on the EDT, saving you a lot of calls to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `paintComponent` method in a JPanel. You can do it by using something like this.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){

    @Overide
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paint();
        // Draw Stuff Here

    }

};
```

***The reason you are not getting the ball to move across the frame is that you are not calling the repaint method.*** You should do so on a thread.

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Overide
    public void run(){
        while(frame.isVisible()){
            ball.moveBall();     
            panel.repaint();
            try{Thread.sleep(5);}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
});
```

Also, why are you making ball a instance of the PaintTest class? To get only one frame and ball you would want to add a class named `Ball` and use that to make an instance:

```
public class Ball{

    int x, y;

    public Ball(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

***That is why you were getting 2 frames.***

Then you would want to get rid of the x and y variables in the main class. To make an instance using this class you would do:

```
Ball ball = new Ball(x, y);
```

Then to paint the ball in the `paintComponent` method you would do:

```
g.fillOval(ball.x, ball.y, 35, 35);
```

Comment: where would I create this JPanel? in my constructor?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well I just changed hs code to use a JPanel, didn't change anything else.

Comment: @Cookie you would create the panel in the constructor, yes... Also, check out the changes i made to my post, now the ball will be repainted

Answer (score -1):

- You didn't call the `repaint();` method.
- You don't need the `y + 1` part.
- Instead of using the `while(true)` loop, you should use a `for` loop.
- You didn't call the `super.paint()` method.
- You didn't use any `Thread.sleep()`, which made the ball move across instantaneously.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PaintTest extends JFrame {
int x = 8;
int y = 30;

public void moveBall(){
x = x + 1;
//y = y + 1;
try{
    Thread.sleep(500);
} catch(InterruptedException e){

}
repaint();
}
public static void main(String[] args){
PaintTest frame1 = new PaintTest();
PaintTest ball = new PaintTest();

for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
//while(true){
    ball.moveBall();
}
}

public PaintTest() {
super("Paint Test");
setSize(500,500);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
super.paint(g);
super.paint(g2);
g.setColor(Color.magenta);
g.drawLine(0,100,500,100);
g.drawLine(0,101,500,101);
g.drawLine(0,102,500,102);
g.drawLine(0,103,500,103);

g.fillOval(x,y,35,35);
}
}
```

This code will make the ball move across the screen VERY slowly.  If you want to speed it up, change the number of miliseconds in the `Thread.sleep(miliseconds)` part to a smaller number of miliseconds.

Comment: @ManOfPanda That is how you make the ball visible.

Comment: No it's not and you don't want to ever draw within the JFrame itself as you loose all benefit of Swing graphics, all automatic double buffering, and you risk drawing errors in child components, borders, glass panes, etc. It's a dangerous thing to recommend.

Comment: I do need they y+1 so that the ball move down across the frame

Comment: @Cookie Oh ok then use y+1 and the ball will move diagonally from the top right to the bottom left for 100 pixels in my code.